# Understanding a part of code

Tags: c, macros, microcontroller

Here is a part of microcontroller code, which I am not able to understand.

```
#define GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025400))

int main (void){
     GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R = 0x0E;
...}
```

As I understood, GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R is not a vairable, and (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025400)) is the content of the address pointed by the pointed. 
Then how is it possible to use GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R as variable. What is happening here.

Comment: That looks like a typical definition of a memory-mapped I/O register. Note the pointer dereference operator included in the definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#define` declares a preprocessor macro. This means that before compilation `GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R` will be replaced everywhere in the code with the contents of the macro. So your actually compiled code will be

```
(*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025400)) = 0x0E;
```

Which pretty much means write `0x0E` to that address.

Preprocessor macros are often used if you wish to to reference some (complicated) numeric value by a name. This allows you to centrally change that value if you have to, but have a meaningful name in your code without having to have a variable for it.

Comment: But (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025400)) is not a variable, it is just the content of the address.

Comment: @zud No, it is not a variable, it's a static address. But it is an expression that you better keep in a centralised place.

Comment: @zud, It is not a variable, but it _is_ a valid [l-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)), which include variables and addresses.

Answer (score 3):

The constant value 0x40025400 is being used as a *memory address*. It seems that on your platform (a microcontroller), that address is a [memory-mapped general-purpose I/O port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O).

The code is equivalent to this, if it makes it more readable:

```
// pointer to memory address 0x40025400
volatile unsigned long *p = 0x40025400;

// set that value in memory
*p = 0x0E;
```

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr. The assignment isn't to a variable, it is to a specific location in memory.

The macro here can be thought of as just being substitued in for its use.

```
#define GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025400))
int main (void) {
  GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R = 0x0E;
...
```

Could be rewritten as

```
int main (void) {
  (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025400)) = 0x0E;
...
```

Which is just dereferencing the memory address `0x40025400` and assigning it the value 0x0E.